# Empty string when reading into a string from ifstream with noskipws

Tags: c++, gcc

Originally asked [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/23397/).

If I send "Hello world" to cin with the following code...

```
string str,msg;
getline(cin,str);
stringstream ss(str);
char c;
while(ss >> noskipws >> c)
    msg += c;
```

...results in `msg` = `"Hello World"`.

But if I use `string c` instead of `char c`, `msg` is empty.

I am compiling with:
gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3

Why do I get an empty string?

Comment: Please don't (just) link to questions on external websites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an interesting [quote from cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/noskipws/):

> Notice that many extraction operations consider the whitespaces themselves as the terminating character, therfore, with the skipws flag disabled, **some extraction operations may extract no characters at all from the stream**.

Remove the `noskipws` if you want to extract tokens into a string.

Generally, you should consider carefully, and then stick to one of, { line-based, token-based, or character-based } extraction.